# Making a custom function in access vba that has no errors but I am getting no results?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a lot of text and combo boxes on a user form in access. I am in the process of writing vba code for their update events.  Alot of the buttons have the same code so I am writing a function that can be used on multiple combo and text boxes.

I am just going to use a small part of my code for this example,

```
Option Compare Database
Function comboboxupdate(RowNumber As Variant)

        Dim x As Variant
        Dim y As Variant

        x = "tb_LbrRate" & RowNumber & ".Value"
        y = "cb_op" & RowNumber & ".Value"
        x = DLookup("LaborRate", "tblOperationsType", "[operationsID]" = y)

End Function

Private Sub cb_op1_AfterUpdate()

        Call comboboxupdate(1)
        'tb_LbrRate1.Value = DLookup("LaborRate", "tbloperationsType", "[operationsID] = cb_op1.value")

End Sub
```

When I step through the sub routine and function I get no errors, I noticed when I hovered my mouse over the x and y variables it showed in the caption 
x = "tb_LbrRate1.value" y = "cb_op1.value". This looks like the concatenation
is working correctly but I am curious though is it leaving the quotations around the values?? Meaning

"tb_LbrRate1.value" = Dlookup("laborRate"...  instead of
 tb_LbrRate1.value  = Dlookup("laborRate"...

Finally the commented code in after update sub routine works, so I just need my function to emulate this, but have the flexibility to work on multiple combo and list boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is just changing the value of the variable x, it is not referring to the `texbox control which's name is x`. You need to get the control by its name as in the function `GetControlByName` in this thread: [Name of object changes in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451474/name-of-object-changes-in-function)

Then you could:

```
 Dim x as Object, y as object
 set x = GetControlByName("tb_LbrRate" & RowNumber)
 set y = GetControlByName("cb_op" & RowNumber)
 x.Value = DLookup("LaborRate", "tblOperationsType", "[operationsID] = " & y.Value)
```